# Why is Select widget not working in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been trying to create a dashboard of stock market information using bokeh, and I would like to have a dropdown menu that, when you click on one of the options, would change the information plotted depending on what you click.

The graph appears fine, but I can't get it to change using the dropdown menu.

Initially I thought it was a bokeh server problem. Now I've ran the "bokeh serve" command in anaconda prompt, and found this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.3.4/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb that works exactly the way I want it to work when I copy and paste the code into my jupyter notebook. However, when I modify the code to my own data and use Select instead of Slider, the old problem appears.

```
output_notebook()

def modify_dc(doc):

    source = ColumnDataSource(dat[['Date','Close']])

    #Making the glyphs
    big = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', title="Zeiss stock dashboard")
    p = big.line(x = "Date", y = "Close", line_width=2, source=source)

    def update(attr, old, new):
        if new == 'a':
            data = dat[['Date','Traded Volume']]
        else:
            data = dat[['Date','Close']]
        source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
        r.data_source.data = source1.data

    menu = Select(options = ['a','b','c','d'],
                  value='a')
    menu.on_change('value',update)

    doc.add_root(row(menu,big))


show(modify_dc)
```

There were no error messages of any sort. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
r.data_source.data = source1.data
```

Although it looks like a "regular" Python `dict`, the ".data" attribute of a `ColumnDataSource` is actually a very specialized object that handles all the automatic synchronization between Python and JavaScript, and is intimately connected to the CDS it was created on. Moving a `.data` from one CDS to another basically does not work, and, starting with Bokeh 2.0 later this year, trying to do so will raise an exception.

Instead, you can set a CDS `.data` from a plain Python `dict`:

```
source.data = { ... }
```

or in recent versions, directly from a Pandas `DataFrame`:

```
source.data = some_df
```

Comment: Hi, so I replaced the two lines you mentioned and just wrote "source.data = data" in the update function, and it still does not work.

Comment: Without a complete self-contained example that could actually be run and investigated, it's impossible to speculate further. There are several examples with Select widgets that you can refer to and emulate, e.g [app/population.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/population.py), [app/stocks](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/stocks), [app/ohlc](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/ohlc) and [app/movies](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/movies)